# How can I prevent a user from opening more than one form at a time?

Tags: vb.net

I have developed an application in VB.NET. It has 20 forms. All 20 can be opened from a menu strip control. The user should be able to open only one form at a time. How might I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You could make all the forms modal, then the user will have to close one form before opening another

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Using modality won't even allow the MDIParent to be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Just add in this code where you have written code to open new form within MDI parent. Assuming MDIParent1 is your MDI form name:

```
    If Not IsNothing(MDIParent1.ActiveMdiChild) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your MDI Parent form and lets call it CloseChildForms

```
Private Sub CloseChildForms()

    Try

        If Not IsNothing(Me.ActiveMdiChild) Then

            Me.ActiveMdiChild.Close()

        Else

            Exit Sub

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        'Handle your exceptions

    End Try

End Sub
```

Now, before opening any other form, just call this method.